# Не работает цикл for

Tags: javascript

Писал простенькую функцию, и обнаружил что не работает цикл for. Вроде бы все правильно. Тут же его переписал, а старую закомментировал, вуаля все работает. Почему два абсолютно одинаковых кода (цикла), и один не работает?

```
function filter()
{
    var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    alert(arr.length);             // <= 8           

    for (var count = 0; count < arr.length; count++)  // <= работает. Выводит 8 раз bla bla bla
    {
        alert("bla bla bla");
    }

    for (var count = 0; count < arr.lenght; count++)  // <= не работает. 
    {                
        alert("bla bla bla");
    }           
}
```

Писал это дело в Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. Проверял в разных браузерах и онлайн интерпретаторах. Дело в том что это не в первый раз. Хотелось бы разобраться в чем дело.

Comment: Все разобрался во втором случае lenght а не length... Почему то в отладчике не было ошибки.

Comment: потому что яваскрипт позволяет обращаться к свойствам которых нет в объекте, просто они будут иметь значение _undefined_

Comment: Спасибо, понял.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все просто, во втором `for` ты указал несуществующее свойство массивов leng**ht**, хотя нужно leng**th**. Но ды подобные ошибки считаются опечатками;)

```
for (var count = 0; count < arr.length; count++) {
    alert("bla bla bla");
}

for (var count = 0; count < arr.lenght; count++) {                 
    alert("bla bla bla");
}
```

Comment: Да, я уже нашел, спасибо. Все утро просидел )

Comment: @Nikolay ну ды понятное дело, ведь ошибки по сути нет, ты просто использовал свойство типа undefined:) поэтому будь повнимательнее;)